# Install Numpy-stl on WIN10

Tags: numpy, 3d, mesh, numpy-stl

I am trying to use the package "numpy-stl" and as you see i am a beginner in programming.

I don't know how to install this package. I tried it with pip but I don't know even understand how to do that.

I am using Python with Anaconda and PyCharm as IDE on WIN10.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Anaconda, run the following command to install numpy-stl as shown on the Anaconda's Numpy-stl [page](https://anaconda.org/prkrekel/numpy-stl):
`conda install -c prkrekel numpy-stl`

You can install it with pip using: `pip install numpy-stl`.